# Mock Spark DataFrameReader .option

Tags: java, apache-spark, testing, mockito, spock

I want to parametrice when i have a header and then separator when I read a csv from Spark. I've written this:

```
DataFrameReader dataFrameReader = spark.read();

    dataFrameReader = "csv".equalsIgnoreCase(params.getReadFileType()) ?
                dataFrameReader
                        .option("sep",params.getDelimiter())
                        .option("header",params.isHeader())
                :dataFrameReader;
```

I'm new to Groovy and I don't get dataFrameReader.option corrected mocked.

```
DataFrameReader dfReaderLoader = Mock(DataFrameReader)
DataFrameReader dfReaderOptionString = Mock(DataFrameReader)
DataFrameReader dfReaderOptionBoolean = Mock(DataFrameReader)

SparkSession sparkSession = Mock(SparkSession)
sparkSession.read() >> dfReaderLoader
dfReaderLoader.option(_ as String, _ as String) >> dfReaderOptionString
dfReaderOptionString.option(_ as String, _ as Boolean) >>  dfReaderOptionBoolean
```

And it gives me a null pointer exception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.option(String, boolean)" because
> the return value of
> "org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.option(String, String)" is null

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time. Because it is Xmas, I did the leg work for you this once. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the params.I was not sending Delimiter or Header so it gave error.

Comment: That is why you should share more of your code (next time), nobody here had a chance to discover this error other than you.

Comment: Sorry, I will do well next time.

Comment: This is not an answer, just an abstract claim without proof. After you wasted two volunteers' time already, at least write a comprehensive answer proving your point. Look at the other two answers. They show code and even link to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) versions which you can execute online. The latter is not necessary, but at least provide a minimal, but complete answer (code under test + test), also explaining your faulty code before and how you fixed it. Otherwise, nobody learns from your experience. SO is a community, please remember that. Thank you so much.

Comment: I mean, I can imagine how a problem in the parameters can lead to the first `option` call to return `null`, causing the NPE when trying the second one. But imagination is not code. My answer e.g. proves that it works correctly if the parameters are OK, even though I had to guess what your classes under test really look like.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what your problem is, but my guess is that you create the mocks, but then do not inject them into your class under test. If you do that, both your own version as well as Leonard's suggested improved version with a default response work:

**Class under test + helper class:**

```java
class UnderTest {
  SparkSession spark
  Parameters params

  DataFrameReader produce() {
    DataFrameReader dataFrameReader = spark.read()

    dataFrameReader = "csv".equalsIgnoreCase(params.getReadFileType()) ?
      dataFrameReader
        .option("sep", params.getDelimiter())
        .option("header", params.isHeader())
      : dataFrameReader
  }
}
```

```java
class Parameters {
  String readFileType
  String delimiter
  boolean header
}
```

**Spock specification:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q74923254

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.spockframework.mock.MockUtil
import spock.lang.Specification

class DataFrameReaderTest extends Specification {
  def 'read #readFileType data'() {
    given:
    DataFrameReader dfReaderLoader = Mock(DataFrameReader)
    DataFrameReader dfReaderOptionString = Mock(DataFrameReader)
    DataFrameReader dfReaderOptionBoolean = Mock(DataFrameReader)

    SparkSession sparkSession = Mock(SparkSession)
    sparkSession.read() >> dfReaderLoader
    dfReaderLoader.option(_ as String, _ as String) >> dfReaderOptionString
    dfReaderOptionString.option(_ as String, _ as Boolean) >> dfReaderOptionBoolean

    def underTest = new UnderTest(spark: sparkSession, params: parameters)

    expect:
    underTest.produce().toString().contains(returnedMockName)

    where:
    readFileType | parameters                                                               | returnedMockName
    'CSV'        | new Parameters(readFileType: readFileType, delimiter: ';', header: true) | 'dfReaderOptionBoolean'
    'XLS'        | new Parameters(readFileType: readFileType)                               | 'dfReaderLoader'
  }

  def 'read #readFileType data (improved)'() {
    given:
    SparkSession sparkSession = Mock() {
      read() >> Mock(DataFrameReader) {
        _ >> _
      }
    }

    def parameters = new Parameters(readFileType: readFileType, delimiter: ';', header: true)
    def underTest = new UnderTest(spark: sparkSession, params: parameters)

    expect:
    new MockUtil().isMock(underTest.produce())

    where:
    readFileType << ['CSV', 'XLS']
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJy1VW1P2zAQ_p5fceo-JJU6SxSmaRll00Bsk9iLKEyTpqkyybVEpHGwXco0-O8720nqpIVKY-uH1HYeP3f33EtKnlzxGUKKTCVyMZ_MudIomdL0QtygnOZiya5f7r0a7g5f7AVBNi-F1CDkjPGSJ5d0r-TyiqnrnB1xzY8ln-Mp8hTlo9ixWY1RqUwUPlCVIrmaGpKlIOicduwTPc51ltc4i2E5L2ZEg0k2zRKuDU_w9r3kF1HYtRjb53OyOxmynWG8y3bZTtgPkpwrBR23z1BpwFuNRaqgxQ-_AyClphBKQsIz8zzOcjz7VZKCxBJGfYsBmGU3WMR22aGHdOoWJ8JuR2DCizqo_qNXv5TGnbGWWTF7AsE7IXLkxYMMlsJPFCh_U13zAc6qj2JGJJLl4KATuEW2j5iwbkUT4KS8jW4A3qbF4mvQ4vJfPMxYxb6BsnrjojfZXhR1VYygwCWc1_vIFVcr3gHQhs9V7P6RmklVSuItFZN2RdFwslKKdJFg1GdaOA9pmYhC86xQkUS9kAWmRunPRFdRLS9RomNqFeGdZxWe9ruDrm1rLjwcfwtXGKPH18Zk5DsTt1wbkJR5Ns8IFkP4OhzApdU8Bi0X2CeqcGMaQmf1-8n4b6z2twYZtkvQmLsPtrQ5RDSIJE3HtL-x47e2TH3HZc91x8YWbHBAVUugSbW9D9yzqVEv7aN_lpT_2gGGpx7sVPGZsgJs6IstJb-_Dz9sUQ5clfys9LKJJIXcjG88toquJ4gOV4pVARi73QHaeFVlZm3AdvYjR19NwSpfa5heom56DK8XPFcfZ4WQeMgVRs4NNkN96kVMisCbqg46VE2x1HOvp7Ds1QkxREd1vo2ua2iX_dWFTH2wJytwvMGkJ7OnodXZfaH8fK1Om9Kjo4vqS-QcIL4_ZATBaw).

The result should look similar to this in your IDE:

```
DataFrameReaderTest ✔
├─ read #readFileType data ✔
│  ├─ read CSV data ✔
│  └─ read XLS data ✔
└─ read #readFileType data (improved) ✔
   ├─ read CSV data (improved) ✔
   └─ read XLS data (improved) ✔
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really care about the intermediate invocations of a builder pattern, i.e. an object that returns itself. I'd suggest to use a `Stub`, which will return itself, if the method return type matches it's type, or you can use this [declaration](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#_returning_a_default_response) `_ >> _` to achieve the same for `Mocks`.

```
given:
ThingBuilder builder = Mock() {
  _ >> _
}

when:
Thing thing = builder
  .id("id-42")
  .name("spock")
  .weight(100)
  .build()

then:
1 * builder.build() >> new Thing(id: 'id-1337') // <-- only assert the last call you actually care about
thing.id == 'id-1337'
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxVUcFuwjAMvecrrF5I0RbBmDQJqWjaxHEndkdZkqYRbVKlGQUh_n1umsLoIXWc5_ee7ZaLA9cKnNesa504lJ43qnf-wKQTHTM2KM9FMM4SYprW-QARx2puNdu1SpjSCP4A0N6545kFz21XOt-wn19TS-XZnBBR866DjzGxPfGmrdXAAuoUlJUdPFDChRAAqUrIIgeiYkVGc3wC_LQ5KruO4XdlrE7MkCShgC90e4MD7GGzgX28XEn89dUDA4R4FhNFqmNG0szI59eXLJ9SFmdFsziPe7JXRleBLheLWyoy0XyUCze5JcwnkQkymLOqH51QI9cwQ83lavU2y1M1PqAXKIr7Exl6wW7SdMc2hoZ3wQ_h4PN-MxJjXCyMTmPhe5obTX4QyoPSZxzDFhfjLa-n1BPgTj-jUDFK5f91pwVcrn_YxrqM).

That being said, the error would probably go away if you just remove the `as String` cast of the second argument of `option`, or fix it to be `as Boolean` as the error suggests.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. DataFrameReader does not follow builder pattern and I've no problem mocking other methods like format or load. I cannot get any kind of option (String, String or String, Boolean,....) mocked and I don't know why.

Comment: @Observer `DataFrameReader does not follow builder pattern`, what I mean is that an object returns itself when configuring it, and that is that the `option` methods to.